# Encountered problem when using pptp in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I tried to use pptp in Ubuntu 10.10 and encountered the following error (ip address, username, and password have been omitted)

> sudo pptpsetup --create vpn --server
>
> XXX --username XXX --password XXX
>
> --start Using interface ppp0 Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1 CHAP
>
> authentication succeeded Cannot
>
> determine ethernet address for proxy
>
> ARP local  IP address XXX remote IP
>
> address XXX

Could anyone figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that is an error?

From the [known working log](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#log):

```
...
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 168.192.232.42>]
Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
local IP address 168.192.232.42
remote IP address 168.192.232.31
...
```